# The RSS feed for the Podcasts no longer include the media elements required by Podcast apps

Tags: bug, feed, blog, podcast

The RSS [feed for the podcasts](http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/podcasts/feed/) on the new blog do not include the media embed tags needed for most podcast consuming software to pick up the actual episodes.

At the moment they only include an embedded SoundCloud iframe in the content element, which isn't picked up.

#### Expected:

```
<item>
  <title> [...] </title>
  <link>http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/stack-exchange-podcast-66-thank-you-for-saying-words-to-us/</link>
  <category><![CDATA[ company ]]></category>
  <category><![CDATA[ podcasts ]]></category>
  <comments/>
  <pubDate>Mon, 03 Aug 2015 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
  <guid/>
  <description> [...] </description>
  <content:encoded> [...] </content>
  <enclosure url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/220469343/download?client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea" length="49652864" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <media:content url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/220469343/download?client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea" fileSize="49652864" type="audio/mpeg" medium="audio" expression="full" duration="3795" />
  <itunes:duration>3795</itunes:duration>
</item>
```

Is there an alternative feed URL I can use?

SoundCloud do not appear to expose a direct feed on their pages or in the metadata on the page.

Currently using Podcast Lounge on Windows Phone, but inspecting the feed manually shows the same lack of media elements.

Comment: I read in the tech news [Nimbus for Soundcloud](http://www.windowscentral.com/nimbus-soundcloud-windows-phone) app for windows phone. See if it works for you.

Comment: Sadly not - the issue is that the RSS feed no longer includes the media elements required, and SoundCloud do not expose this by default either.

Comment: It seems like SoundCloud does support hosting podcasts out of their service: http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1209292-can-i-podcast-with-soundcloud-. Is the problem that it's not enabled? That seems too simple...

Comment: Yes, it's something the channel owner needs to enable, as it's not "on by default", but I believe that it is something that can be done by all channel owners now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The podcast feed was an unforeseen casualty when the blog was updated to its [shiny new iteration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/).

Now that six to eight weeks have passed, the issue has been fixed and your podcast player should automatically redirect to the new feed and start picking up new, and missed episodes.

If needed, **the canonical URL for the podcast feed is: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/** as per [Abby's official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264230/281117).