# Stack exchange podcast feed gone?

Tags: support, feed, podcast

Previously it seemed that the stack exchange RSS feed was at http://blog.stackexchange.com/?feed=podcast

This no longer points to an RSS feed. Looking around, the options seem to be http://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/, which has podcasts and blog entries (undesirable because of RSS feed clutter), and https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/feed/, which is limited to podcasts only, but doesn't actually contain the *media files*, and so is useless for podcatchers. What is the correct RSS feed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The canonical URL for the podcast feed is now: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/

301 redirects have now been set up from old feed URLs to the new canonical one, so subscriptions should update automatically. We are working on re-submitting to the iTunes store to get that piece settled too (once some final kinks are worked out).

The [blog is now open source](http://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog), so you can see what's been done to the feeds to elicit current behavior or even submit a pull request if you think there are improvements to be made. ([Here's the latest major update to the feed](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/165).)

Comment: https:// also works, apparently, though evidently the security is stripped before the actual mp3 is downloaded. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul No prob! Your question was perfectly timed - we literally *just* got this up :)

Comment: It's Shog9's sockpuppet! Or maybe Oded's or even yours! >)

Comment: The sidebar blog link is broken. http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/stack-exchange-podcast-67-the-firehose-of-nerd-dom/?cb=1 doesn't work. It needs to be: http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/stack-exchange-podcast-67-anil-dash-and-the-firehose-of-nerd-dom/

Comment: @Mazura I'm on mobile now, but when I left the office there were two links: one working, and one still bad (which should drop off soon - caching).